# Using HTML agility pack on WP7.5

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, html-agility-pack, windows-phone-7.1

Is there a reference/guide for using HTML Agility Pack on WP7.5? I tried compiling the source on my VS2010 but I wasn't able to reference the DLL created on my local machine. Basically, I'm looking for a text extractor to obtain the text from a given URL. I understand that the HTML Agility Pack works best. Any ideas/suggestions? Thanks :)

Comment: Did you compile for the compact framework?

Comment: Can you let me know which compact framework are you referring to? I compiled the HTML Agility Pack solution available at the codeplex source and generated a DLL which I tried to reference in my WP7 project. I was unable to reference the DLL in my WP7 project. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I was the one who created that discussion. As said in that discussions page, the solution to this problem is to reference the System.Xml.XPath DLL from the MSFT SDK\Silverlight 4.0\Client folder. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Which solution did you load? The HAPPhone.sln solution in the latest build looks to be what should build a phone project. You can't reference any of the other solutions or DLLs created because they won't be compiled for the phone.

Jaapjan in the comment essentially was saying this but using the term "compact framework" for WP7, while technically interchangeable, will throw most people off. Basically put, you can't use a .NET 4.0 dll on a WP7/Silverlight/CompactFramework build because they're not the same.

I'll conclude this by saying I've not actually used this but if I were to need it, I would be using the HAPPhone solution. If that's the one you've been using and those DLLs don't work, there may be another issue entirely at play.

I think you may've also been the one that posted on their discussion thread here: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/282469. If so, you kind of answered your own question and could've gave yourself some points, ;P. I'll respond to the discussion too since I know what's up unless someone beats me to it...