# Obtaining text from HTML on WP7 using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to extract text from HTML using HtmlAgilityPack. I successfully added HtmlAgilityPack to my project. However, I tried the following code to extract the body text:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

// There are various options, set as needed
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags=true;

// filePath is a path to a file containing the html
htmlDoc.Load(filePath);

// Use:  htmlDoc.LoadXML(xmlString);  to load from a string

// ParseErrors is an ArrayList containing any errors from the Load statement
if (htmlDoc.ParseErrors!=null && htmlDoc.ParseErrors.Count>0)
{
    // Handle any parse errors as required
}
else
{
    if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
    {
        HtmlNode bodyNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");

        if (bodyNode != null)
        {
            // Do something with bodyNode
        }
    }
}
```

and I receive the following error when building the project.

Error 1 The type 'System.Xml.XPath.IXPathNavigable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml.XPath, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. D:\test\test\MainPage.xaml.cs 58

I should add that I added the System.Xml reference and I still get this error. Can you please help me out what this issue? Thanks.

Comment: With HAP on the phone you'll have to use Linq2Xml to find stuff in the parsed HTML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using HTML agility pack on WP7.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454959/using-html-agility-pack-on-wp7-5)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks. I figured out that I had to add a reference to the System.Xml.XPath from the Silverlight 4.0 folder available in the Microsoft SDKs parent folder.

Comment: This didn't work for me in terms of Windows Phone 8. Any clue?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\Client\System.Xml.XPath.dll

Comment: Hay thats awesome ... Yes, Add reference from Silverlight 4.0 folder. Thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

With HAP on the phone you'll have to use Linq2Xml to find stuff in the parsed HTML.  And you might have to build the phone version from the source (HAPPhone).

```
public void Hap()
{
   HtmlWeb.LoadAsync("http://www.page.com", OnCallback);              
}



private void OnCallback(object s, HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted htmlDocumentLoadCompleted)
        {            
            var htmlDocument = htmlDocumentLoadCompleted.Document;

            var test = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("select").ToList();


            var test2 = (from h in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("select")
                         where h.Attributes["id"].Value == "stateDropdown"
                         select h).FirstOrDefault().ChildNodes.ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It says you need to add a reference to System.Xml.**XPath** not System.Xml.